# How to disable or stop showing FCM notifications to the end user in phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap

I have developed an application in phonegap. In that I will receive notifications from the FCM as I will subscribe to a topic. But the notification should not be displayed to the user. I have already tried by commenting NotificationManager.notify method. It doesn't help for me.

Please give any suggestion how to stop showing notifications to the end-user